Screen is zoomed in/is panning/is scrolling
I don't see the whole desktop, but only part of it, and can move to different parts of the desktop by using the mouse. This is extremely annoying! How do I get rid of that?
I tried to change the resolution with the "Display" settings, and also used xrandr to set the correct resolution. I also found the --panning 0x0 option of xrandr and used it, to no avail.

I went through the system settings, and in the "Accessibility" part, there was the option "Desktop Zoom" -> "Enable zoom" checked. When I disabled that, my screen went back to normal.
